# Get Random Value Either 1 or 3 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how I can create Random 1 or 3 (not Range, only 1 or 3) on each load of document? I already tried this but it returns String instead of numbers.Should I have to  parse them to numbers or is there a better way to do this?

```
var num = [];
var chances = "13";
for (var i = 0; i <1; i++) {
  num.push(chances.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chances.length)));
}

console.log(num);
```

Comment: What's the actual end goal with the code above as a whole? I've identified a couple of issues with the code, but if I knew what you actually wanted the code to do, I could probably be more helpful.

Comment: if the numbers you want to have are already into a string, `var num = +chances[Math.floor(Math.random()*chances.length)] `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `Math.random` returns a number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive):

```
var value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 3;
```

That said, note that your `chances` string doesn't have a character at index 3, it's only two characters long, and their indexes are 0 and 1. So if you really want to randomly pick from those two characters, as your code seems to suggest, what you really want is:

```
var value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
```

or

```
var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

...although your code using `chances.length` is just fine (since `chances.length` is `2`).

Also note that `for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)` will only run exactly **once**, making the loop somewhat pointless. :-)

Comment: thanks T.J. Crowder but I am getting `0` or `1` now!

Comment: what I need is `1` or `3`

Comment: @Behseini, Use `value` as index of your **string** or `array` if input is like `[1,3]`

Comment: @Behseini: If you need 1 or 3, see the first code block in the answer. If you need the first or second character from `chances`, see the second and third code blocks from the answer and use `value` with `.charAt` (although your original code is just fine for that use case). Since you've ignored my question above, I can't really help you further.